# ElastcSearch - 32 Core + 198 GB of memory - all CPU hits 100% during Search test

Tags: elasticsearch

We have 2 node clusters each node having 32 core  + 198 GB of memory + locally attached storage.

Running a search query ( for around 15 minutes ) all CPU hits 100% CPU.
I can infer from iostat that I/O is not bottleneck ( %io-utilization is 0 and io queue length is 0 ) and Heap size never goes beyond 2 GB. JVM heap allocated is around 24 GB. Number of search threads 1re 96 ( Num-of-Cores * 3 )

Any suggestion/recommendation, where the bottleneck is or is this behavior is expected ?
We are using ES 1.2.x

Thanks
Raj

Comment: Did you closed your client after each query? Like the code shows: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#transport-client

Comment: Can you post the example query you are running?  How much data is it querying over?

Comment: Thanks for response. Our test case is 3 million documents and size of each document is around 1 K. Sample query looks like {"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"terms": {"UUID.id": [${UUIDs}]}}]}}}},"sort": {"published": "desc"}}. Where UUIDs can be 6-20 UUIds. We want to search all document matching any UUID in query. As number of documents increases in Index, query slows down significantly. I am intrigued to observe that all 32 core CPUs are 100% busy during search. JVM heap does not cross more than 2 GB. As described bottleneck is not in I/O.